# Why I cant redirect the output of PRINT to console?

Tags: batch-file

This:

```
@echo ###########>printable.txt
@print /d:con  printable.txt 1>nul 2>nul
```

ALWAYS produces output to the console:

```
###########
♀
```

not matter how the output is redirected .Piping to MORE or FINDSTR will not help.

Is it possible to redirect the PRINT to the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection works only with stdin, stdout, and stderr file streams. A pipe works exclusively via stdout.

You can direct PRINT to write to the console device, causing the output to appear on the screen. But that is not going through stdout or stderr, so it does not do any good.

PRINT writes directly to a device, not to stdout or stderr. So I don't think there is any way to do what you want.